# I create Kafka in Googlecloud. But i can't connect with Kafka and Databricks

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, databricks, kafka-python

I create Kafka in Googlecloud. But i can't connect with Kafka and Databricks

[image]

Comment: Use the external GCE VM address, not the internal one. Also, you're not using Spark here

Comment: Thank you. I'm try external and internal GCE VM address, but i don't. What else can i try?

Comment: `10.x.x.x` addresses are internal to GCP. Probably not going to be accessible from Databricks if it's not on the same VPC network

Comment: You may also want to read this https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/